# yii2 массив geoJson

Tags: массивы, yii2, geojson

Как получить такой массив ? Заранее спасибо!!!

```
$geoJson = [      
    'type' => 'FeatureCollection',  
        'features' => [
            [
            'type' => 'Feature',
            'geometry' => [
                'type'=> "Point",
                "coordinates" => [ -16.5471268,28.4136726 ]
            ]
        
    ],
]];
```

Данные будут браться из базы

`$clients = Propertys::find()->limit(10)->all();`

Answer (score 0):

Видимо не корректно задал вопрос ;) Вообщем отвечу сам, добился желаемого результата, вот это помогло https://gist.github.com/wboykinm/5730504

Ну и сам код

```
public function actionGeo()
    {
        $propertys = Propertys::find()->limit(10)->all();
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $geojson = [
            'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
            'features'  => []
        ];
        foreach ($propertys as $object) {
            $feature = [
                'type' => 'Feature',
                'geometry' => [
                    'type' => 'Point',
                    'coordinates' => [$object->lng, $object->lat]
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    "Name" => "Gran Hotel, Puerto de la Cruz",
                    "year" => '1890',
                    "month" => "February",
                    "days" => "11-13th",
                    "organiser" => "Pedro Reid, English tradesman living in Puerto de la Cruz",
                    "eventType" => "funfair",
                    "notes" => ""
                ]
            ];
            # Add feature arrays to feature collection array
            array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
        }
        return $geojson;
    }
```